# Syncing a CardDav Adressbook with Thunderbird SOGo Connector

Tags: linux, sync, thunderbird, address-book

I'm using thunderbird/lighting for several mail accounts and calenders under Ubuntu in the Gnome3 Desktop. I also want to sync my CardDav adress book. Right now I am doing that with [Inverse SOGo Connector 24.0.2](http://www.sogo.nu/english/downloads/frontends.html). This is tool is not that great its missing two key features:

- its not syncing automatically but one has to rightclick - then sync every time
- it is not possible to save the account name or password of the carddav server - it is prompted every time

I am confused since this a very common application isn't it? I couldn't find any alternatives for thunderbird. Is there maybe a solution which is based on Linux/Ubuntu? Like syncing the carddav server with a local file and keep thunderbird sync with that local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your CardDAV password using [Saved Password Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/saved-password-editor/). You can even disable/remove the add-on once your password has been saved. (For detailed instructions in German, see [Problem: Passwort wird immer wieder abgefragt](https://posteo.de/hilfe/wie-kann-ich-mein-thunderbird-adressbuch-mit-posteo-abgleichen)). In order to avoid entering the master password (if you’ve set one, which seems advisable) multiple times, I use [StartupMaster](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/startupmaster/), which doesn’t always succeed in limiting the number of password prompts, but often enough for it to pay off imho.

As for the auto-sync – I’m not 100% sure why, but my configuration with SOGo Connector 24.0.*4* seems to sync on startup. I set the periodic sync to 5 mins and enabled the notifications on startup. Even if it shouldn’t sync right away, it will after five minutes. I always get a notification right after the start.